# What determines which name is selected when calling ToString() on an enum value which has multiple corresponding names?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, clr, tostring

### What determines which name is selected when calling `ToString()` on an `enum` value which has multiple corresponding names?

*Long explanation of question follows below.*

I have determined that this not determined uniquely by any of: alphabetical order; declaration order; nor, name length.

For example, consider that I want to have an enum where the numeric values correspond directly to a practical use, (e.g. rgb values for color).

```
public enum RgbColor 
{
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff
}
```

Now, with this enum, calling `default(RgbColor)` will return the rgb value for black.  Let's say I don't want the default value to be black, because I want UI designers to be able to use a call to "Default" when they don't have specific instructions about what color to use.  For now, the Default value for UI designers to use is actually "Blue", but that could change.  So, I add an additional `TextDefault` definition on the enum, and now it looks like:

```
public enum RgbColorWithTextDefaultFirst
{
    TextDefault = 0x0000ff,
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff
}
```

Now, I have tested this and I find that calling `RgbColorWithTextDefaultFirst.TextDefault.ToString()` and `RgbColorWithTextDefaultFirst.Blue.ToString()` both yield "Blue".  So, I figured that the name that is declared last will overwrite the name of the previous declarations.  To test my assumption, I wrote:

```
public enum RgbColorWithTextDefaultLast
{
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff,
    TextDefault = 0x0000ff 
}
```

However, to my surprise, `RgbColorWithTextDefaultLast.Blue.ToString()` and `RgbColorWithTextDefaultLast.TextDefault.ToString()`.  My next guess is that it sorts the names by alphabetical order and returns the first one.  To test this I try:

```
public enum RgbColorWithATextDefaultFirst
{
    ATextDefault = 0x0000ff,
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff
}

public enum RgbColorWithATextDefaultLast
{
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff,
    ATextDefault = 0x0000ff
}
```

Now, for all four of `RgbColorWithATextDefaultFirst.ATextDefault.ToString()`, `RgbColorWithATextDefaultFirst.Blue.ToString()`, `RgbColorWithATextDefaultLast.ATextDefault.ToString()`, `RgbColorWithATextDefaultLast.Blue.ToString()`, I end up with "Blue".  I realize that there is another distinguishing factor, which is length of the string.  My guess is now that the selected name is determined by the length of the name string.  So, my test is to use these declarations:

```
public enum RgbColorWithALast
{
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff,
    A = 0x0000ff
}

public enum RgbColorWithAFirst
{
    A = 0x0000ff,
    Black   = 0x000000,
    Red     = 0xff0000,
    Green   = 0x00ff00,
    Blue    = 0x0000ff,
    White   = 0xffffff
}
```

Now, guess what value I got for all of: `RgbColorWithAFirst.A.ToString()`; `RgbColorWithAFirst.Blue.ToString()`; `RgbColorWithALast.A.ToString()`, `RgbColorWithALast.Blue.ToString()`.  That's right, "Blue".

At this point, I've given up on trying to figure out what determines this by guessing.  I opened up reflector, and I'm going to take a look and try to figure this out, but I figured I would ask a question here to see if anyone here already knows the answer, which is, again: **What determines which name is selected when calling `ToString()` on an `enum` value which has multiple corresponding names?**

Comment: As I'm reading the source code, it's starting to look like it *should* be determined by declaration order, but that it doesn't work in certain cases.  This feels like a little too much like ["select is broken"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html), so I'm going to keep looking.

Comment: To add a datum point: In Mono 2.10 I get the exact opposite: All ways the non-Blue value is displayed.

Comment: the [MSDN documentation for Enum.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx) has more or less the same example and implies that the result is undetermined (see the part that says "The method can return either "Gray" or "Grey", and your code should not make any assumptions about which string will be returned")

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, grazie - based on the code I'm reading I understand why they wouldn't want to guarantee any result for that case, but I don't buy that it's nondeterministic.

Comment: @smartcaveman I'm not saying it's necessarily nondeterministic (which is rarely the case in non multi-threaded code...). Just that the internals you're looking at with Reflector are not guaranteed to behave always in the same way and the MSDN explicitly warns you not to rely on whatever regularity in behavior you discover. That said, I'm all for breaking things down to see how they work...

Comment: But I don't agree with the use of "corresponding name".  That second value is the type and the default is int.  .NET does not force the type values to be unique but if they are not then expect unexpected behavior.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think your approach doesn't make sense... If Blue and TextDefault have the same value, how will you distinguish them? If the enum values are actual color values, you can't have a "default" value without suppressing a color. And `default(RgbColor)` will always return Black, since the default value of any enum is always 0...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, definitely fair.  This particular example was contrived for simplicity.  However, can you imagine a situation where an integral value would have multiple aliases, but only one is canonical?

Comment: @smartcaveman, I didn't realize this was just an example... Of course the question is still relevant, but I don't know the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be going too far here, but I think **it's decided by binary search of the sorted values, and so can depend on the parity of the total number of values**. You can illustrate this with your last example (`RgbColorWithAFirst` and `RgbColorWithALast`) by defining another value in both - then you get `A` from all the `ToString` invocations.

I got here by decompiling `mscorlib` (4.0) and noting that eventually we get to a call to `Array.BinarySearch` on a sorted array of the declared values. Naturally, the binary search stops as soon as it gets a match, so to get it to switch between two identical values the easiest way is to alter the search tree, by adding an extra value.

Of course, this is an implementation detail and should not be relied on. It seems to me that in your case you would be best served by using `DescriptionAttribute` on enum values where you want to be explicit about the display value, and a helper method such as:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string Description(this Enum value)
    {
        var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                            field, 
                            typeof (DescriptionAttribute)) 
                        as DescriptionAttribute;

        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this at first too, but the call to `Array.BinarySearch()` takes an array of `int` (the underlying values).  Adding another values, will affect the result by altering the BST, but it isn't the only determining factor.  I think `Type.GetEnumData` is a little wacky too, but it at least shows that the starting point is the reflection call to `GetFields`

Comment: Yes, we pass an array of the underlying values (*including* duplicates), we get back the *index* of the first-found match, and we use that index in an array of the names.

Comment: If you open up your DLL in Reflector and have a look at your enum the fields won't be in the order you defined them. I'm pretty sure that the compiler orders a type's fields alphabetically so that will also have some bearing on the result you get.

Comment: @dez, that's not accurate.  I think you may be confused, because enums are often defined in alphabetical order by convention.  Checkout `BindingFlags` for a counterexample

Comment: @smartcaveman Ah, no, it seems both Reflector and ILDASM order them alphabetically (on my machine at least). Using GetFields() is giving me the original order. It seems ILDASM also orders the fields of types other than enums alphabetically whereas Reflector doesn't. I am definitely confused.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation warns that duplicate values will produce errors.
You have duplicate values and are getting errors - not a surprise.

You are getting the first Equal.
Equal is based solely on value.
You have no control over the order in which the enum is evaluated.

As stated in comment an enum expects unique values for the type.

[Enumeration Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

*However, you should not do this because the implicit expectation is that an enum variable will only hold one of the values defined by the enum. To assign an arbitrary value to a variable of an enumeration type is to introduce a high risk for errors.*

Apparently you have uncovered one of the high risk errors with a duplicate values for type.

I characterize this error as non deterministic as I consider changing the order but same data the same input given nothing in the spec state of implies enum input is order dependent.  OP considers different order as different data.  With the OP's assumption would not characterize this a non deterministic.  Still fair to characterized it as an error caused by duplicate values for type.

Another reference that implies uniqueness is expected

[Enum.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx)

The return is string  (not string[]).

Equals is based solely on value.

[Enum.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bafh2by.aspx)

GetName is going to match on the first value.
That is my definition of non-deterministic.
How can you know which you have if have if they are considered equal?

Suspect Microsoft does not enforce uniqueness of enum type values due to overhead.

OP expects that Enum explicitly associates A value with A string (like a KVP) when there is no indication of that type of association.
The documentation explicitly warns against making that assumption.
Where does the documentation indicate Enum is implemented as a set of key value pair,  class, or strut?
The results and methods indicate an Enum is a string and value type (other than char) with a loose association.

Possible work around.

A Dictionary does not require unique values.

```
public enum RgbColor : byte
{
    Black,
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    White,
    Default
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<RgbColor, Int32> ColorRGB = new Dictionary<RgbColor, int>();
    ColorRGB.Add(RgbColor.Black, 0x000000);
    ColorRGB.Add(RgbColor.Default, 0x0000ff);
    ColorRGB.Add(RgbColor.Blue, 0x0000ff);
    ColorRGB.Add(RgbColor.Green, 0x00ff00);
    ColorRGB.Add(RgbColor.White, 0xffffff);

    Debug.WriteLine(ColorRGB[RgbColor.Blue].ToString("X6"));
    Debug.WriteLine(ColorRGB[RgbColor.Default].ToString("X6"));
    Debug.WriteLine(ColorRGB[RgbColor.Black].ToString("X6"));
    Debug.WriteLine(ColorRGB[RgbColor.White].ToString("X6"));
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question.  I am interested in why the results are what they are, not how to get different results.

Comment: But the top part does address why.

Comment: can you prove that it is non-deterministic?  I read the source code, and it certainly doesn't appear that way to me.

Comment: No I cannot prove it is non-deterministic.  How do you prove a negative.  What I am saying is based on that warning I would have no expectation that it be deterministic.

Comment: All you need to do to prove that an algorithm is non-deterministic is to run it twice with the same inputs and get different results.

Comment: Then you have proved it.  Change the order and get different ouput.

Comment: if you change the input (even the order), then it is no longer the same.  My point is that you are wrong about the algorithm being non deterministic

Comment: Ok then that is where we disagree.  Nothing in the spec states the input is order dependent so I call that the same data.  Would you call 1 and 1.0 different input to a decimal?

Comment: yes.  The inputs are different lexical representations of the same value, and interpretation of the lexical inputs as values is part of the process.  I would allow that `1m` and `1.0m`, are the same inputs as decimal, but only because the type is defined, and we know that the defined type interprets those values equivalently.  However, `1` requires conversion from an integer to a decimal, and `1.0` requires conversion from a floating point to an integer, which are different operations despite evaluating to the same result

Comment: Cool. There is no explicit type definition for enum that I could find.  My inferred type definition is different (not arguing better) from yours. That explains why I would call it non deterministic and you don't.

Comment: not at all related to C#/.NET but after your last comment I found an [interesting Wikipedia article that provides a meta-perspective on enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17571/discussion-between-blam-and-smartcaveman)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is undefined. Even if you are able to show what the result is for some specific version of .NEt it could change. See the [enum.toString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx) documentation, which says:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you
>   attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration
>   member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make
>   any assumptions about which name the method will return. For example,
>   the following enumeration defines two members, Shade.Gray and
>   Shade.Grey, that have the same underlying value.
>
> enum Shade {
>       White = 0, Gray = 1, Grey = 1, Black = 2  }
>
> The following method call attempts to retrieve the name of a member of the Shade
>   enumeration whose underlying value is 1. The method can return either
>   "Gray" or "Grey", and your code should not make any assumptions about
>   which string will be returned.
>
> string shadeName = ((Shade) 1).ToString();

Also see the previous paragraph is documentation, which shows how to retrieve *all* names